# Cannot add name when creating new java class

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated to the last version of android studio, and when I am trying to create new Java file when the window pops-up I cannot fill the name field.

I can fill the other fields "SuperClasses" and "Interfaces", but not the name field.

other files like xml I can create normally.

[image: here is my android studio and gradle version]

[image: here is my android studio and gradle version]

Comment: working fine for me, I'm using linux.

Comment: did you try invalidate caches / restart option?

Comment: It's weird can you able to paste a text to name field ?

Comment: @appersiano - yes I tried.

Comment: @Alperen - Yes it enables pasted text

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason - I am using plugin powerMode2 and update to this plugin caused this weird bug.